# Where is Docker storing the source files for the downloaded image(apache airflow )

Tags: docker, airflow

I downloaded the official Docker image for Apache Airflow but I cannot seem to locate any of the Airflow files on my Mac. Where did they go? I tried to echo $AIRFLOW_HOME but it returns nothing.

I can see the sample DAGs on the UI, but where are they on my machine? I opened the docker compose.yaml, but couldn’t find much.
Also when i run docker-compose up airflow init airflow info, i get a bunch of paths like /opt/ airflow that dont even exist on my Mac.

Comment: The sample DAGs are already present in the source code of the repository, You might find the source code where the docker image is stored probably in /var/lib/docker ...

Comment: Thank you. I created a DAG and as per instruction placed it under the /dags folder and restarted the services. But I can't see my DAG on UI? Do you know why?

Comment: Is it paused? If you're using 2.0 version, you might find it under paused section.